401: Unauthorized issues with second try with valid host, username and password in HttpURLConnection
I have implemented HA in my code, if my primary host fails then it should pick up the secondary host. This happens with the help of a recursive mechanism. I faced a problem in the following scenario.

Valid host, valid username, and wrong password.

I got 401 issues then after 3 retries, the switchover happened successfully for the second host.

Valid host, valid username, and valid password. still, the issues persist.

At the end i am closing the connection but still the issue not resolved why?
            trustAllHosts();
            requestUrl = new URL(urlVal);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
            log.info("connection:"+connection);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();

//retry mechanism
please assist me in resolving this issue.

I tried closing the connection.
Cookies rest tried.
Created two different connections. One for the primary host (request URL looks like this https://host/login?IDToken1=UserName&IDToken2=Password). Another one for the secondary.

Still, the issue is not resolved. What if the password expired for the host, how to resolve this issue?
